# Generate Report in MS Access with Dynamic Layout

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a task to create ad-hoc report generator engine in MS Access where user can select table, fields and criteria, and report will be dynamically generated based on the given parameters.

I create Access form as the interface for user to input the required parameters (using ComboBox and ListBox to select table and field(s)). All tables are stored in Access database. I have successfuly bind list of tables and fields to the ComboBox and ListBox.

My questions is..

How do I generate dynamic report layout based on number of fields selected in the form? Let say if the user choose more fields, the field width will be smaller than if he choose less number of fields (I want the report fit Form/Report View).

FYI, I am working MS Access 2010.

Comment: I generally use HTML, Word and Excel depending on what I want.

Comment: @Remou any technical tutorial that you can share? Actually, I prefer if I can generate the report into sub report inside the form, so it is more comfortable for user to make changes

Answer (score 1):

There is a property called [Can Grow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194664%28v=office.15%29.aspx) just select the field you want to grow and change it to `yes`. Keep in mind however that the CanGrow property does not apply to a form or report page header and page footer sections.

Comment: hi kefash, I understand Can Grow property helps you to make all your words to fit in the textbox. Any idea how to generate the report header dynamically too? So the report header will consist of fields those are selected by the user in the main form

Comment: This doesn't work with form or report header. You will just have to set the label height in the header to about 0.4 so the information can spill over into the next line